# Convolution integral involving sinc function

Tags: integration, convolution

I was asked to show that this convolution integral

> With $u(t)=\cos(\omega t)$, compute $y(t)=g(t)*\cos(\omega t)$ directly by evaluating
>
> $$y(t) = \lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{-T}^T \frac{\sin(\omega_c \tau)}{\pi\tau}\cos(\omega(t-\tau))\ \mathsf d\tau $$
>
> to show 
>   $$
> y(t) = \begin{cases}
> \cos(\omega t),& \text{ for } |\omega|<\omega_c \\\
> \frac12\cos(\omega t),& \text{ for } \omega=\omega_c \\\
> 0,& \text{ for } |\omega|>\omega_c.
> \end{cases}
> $$

results in the answers also given in the image. Not quite sure how to approach this integral, everything seems to be coupled together.

Does anyone know how this kind of integrals is solved?

Comment: It is preferred that you write questions in MathJax so that they are accessible to users with screen readers. I have done this for you (please check for any errors), but here is a tutorial to do so yourself in the future: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, I presume here that $g(t)=\frac{\sin(\omega_c t)}{\pi t}$?